# Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.14 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, susy-sass

A little confusing this message I find. Windows 7 using I am.

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
Gem::LoadError on line ["2064"] of C: Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.14 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Through grunt using this I am.

Packages currently:

```
Sass 3.2.14
Compass 0.12.3 (Alnilam)
susy susy-2.1.1
```

How can I get rid of these messages.

Comment: Please, please *please* always select tags from the autocomplete.  You created two tags that already existed under other names.  Each of these names appears in the autocomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Susy 2 requires Sass 3.3, which is only supported by Compass 1.0 (currently a pre-release). If you want to upgrade Susy, you have to upgrade Compass as well.